# Vagrantfile, AWS Access Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, headless-browser

What are the aws.access_key_id, aws.secret_access_key, aws.keypair_name. And what should their values be?

Snippet from: http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/running-headless-selenium-with-chrome/

It doesn't quite match with the instructions here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws

```
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = 'XXXX'      # Replace this
    aws.secret_access_key = 'XXXX'  # Replace this
    aws.keypair_name = 'XXXX'       # Replace this
    aws.ami = 'ami-7747d01e'        # ubuntu 12.04
    override.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'
    override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/amazon-ubuntu.pem'
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest:4444, host:4444

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the key id and secret access key of your User in amazon web services.

See the manual for where to get: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/AWSCredentials.html

Comment: Isn't the key pair associated with a VM after it has been already made?

Comment: you need to have a key to even launch a new instance